# Is it good practice to redirect to new page in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code which submits a form using JSON. On success, I want to show a single message (say 'Thanks for registering') on a page. I notice that on receiving  200 OK response (with the message 'Thanks for registering'), the browser doesn't display that response in a new page (which I now think is obvious).

Is it better to use window.location to display a new message (which I think is unnecessary communication) or shall I override the existing HTML with new HTML (using something like innerHTML).

Shall I do this:

```
success : function(result) {
                    // you can see the result from the console
                    // tab of the developer tools
                    console.log(result);
                    window.location = "/newreg-success"
                }
```

or shall I change the HTML of existing page?

Comment: You can use a query param.

Comment: Do you mean using window.location is also ok?

Comment: The purpose of AJAX is avoiding page reload. If you run AJAX and then redirect, you're still getting a page reload plus an additional request.

Comment: In normal post, they redirect because user might refresh and make the same request, but in Ajax, this problem doesn't exist, so there is no best practice about it, it's just common sense and usability.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, to change an element, it's better to change the HTML of the page (using `appendChild`, not using `innerHTML`). But if the whole page changed, it will be much less work to use `window.location`.